# I am planning to divide this components and separate into three different components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

- I am new to js.
- I tried to change es5 to es6 classes.
- in my es5 fiddle the tab content works fine
- in my es6 fiddle the tab content works
- but right now I am planning to divide this components and separate into three different components
- and I have imported into one file.
- but I am getting the below three errors
- can you guys tell me how to fix it
- providing my code below.
- in fiddle not sure how to divide my files into separately.

tab contents showing with es6

```
warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `first-time-tab`.

warning.js:45 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `first-time-tab`.

invariant.js:39 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `first-time-tab`.(…)



import React from 'react';
import Tabs from './sports-content';
import Pane from './players-content';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to follow what you're asking but those warnings mean that you tried importing a React component from a file that doesn't export a component, or exports it as a named component instead of default:

Two common ways of exporting in ES6 and how to import them:

```
export default class Tabs extends Component { // logic }
```

To import:

```
import Tabs from 'path/to/file'
```

The second way is with a named export, likely what you did which caused the error:

```
export class Tabs extends Component { // logic }
```

To import:

```
import { Tabs } from 'path/to/file'
```

Notice that in the default case, no curlies are necessary when importing, and you can give it whatever name you want. The downside is that you can only have ONE default export in a file. All others are omitted.

In the second case, you MUST import it with curlies and it MUST have the same name as what is declared in your file. The upside is that you can have multiple named exports in one file.

Comment: so it should be like this code      `FILE 1
export class Tabs extends Component { 
 // logic
 }

FILE 2
export class Pane extends Component { 
 // logic
}

FILE 3
import React from 'react';
import Tabs from './sports-content';
import Pane from './players-content';    `

Comment: No that's wrong. Read what I wrote. You MUST export `default` if you want to import without curlies (`import Pane` versus with curlies like this `import { Pane }`

Comment: so I should change like this.... ` FILE 1 export class Tabs extends Component { // logic } FILE 2 export class Pane extends Component { // logic } FILE 3 import React from 'react'; import { Tabs } from './sports-content'; import { Pane } from './players-content'; `

Comment: in fiddle is possible to import three different files

Comment: You should make them default instead but sure, that should work

Comment: is it correct now ` FILE 1 export default class Tabs extends Component { // logic } FILE 2 export default class Pane extends Component { // logic } FILE 3 import React from 'react'; import { Tabs } from './sports-content'; import { Pane } from './players-content'; `

Comment: No, if you use default exports you import WITHOUT curlies. Cmon man, try reading the answer before asking more questions. It's really all there.

Comment: sorry to bug you...I read the answer...after reading the answer I gave solution....can you update in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/udsv118m/  I am so confused :(

Comment: You're not bugging, it's alright. It's just confusing to know what you think is wrong. I updated it here https://jsfiddle.net/udsv118m/1/

Comment: can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600485/trying-to-change-all-the-components-into-es6